# add local channel to .condarc on windows

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I want to add local channel to conda on my **windows** machine.
I added to required line in my .condarc file, my file look like:

```
channels:
  - C:\Users\sofirx077029\Desktop\cache\
  - defaults

auto_update_conda: true
always_yes: false
show_channel_urls: true
changeps1: true
add_pip_as_python_dependency: true
use_pip: true
offline: false
allow_softlinks: false
anaconda_upload: false
```

I created the **cache** folder and put there some conda packages, which I download from Anaconda Repo.

now for example when I tried to install conda package:

```
conda install xlrd
```

I get this in my command windows:

> C:\Users\sofirx077029>conda install xlrd Fetching package metadata
>   .... WARNING: The remote server could not find the noarch directory
>   for the requested channel with url:
>   file:///C:/Users/sofirx077029/Desktop/cache
>
> It is possible you have given conda an invalid channel. Please
>   double-check your conda configuration using `conda config --show`.
>
> If the requested url is in fact a valid conda channel, please request
>   that the channel administrator create `noarch/repodata.json` and
>   associated `noarch/repodata.json.bz2` files, even if
>   `noarch/repodata.json` is empty. $ mkdir noarch $ echo '{}' >
>   noarch/repodata.json $ bzip2 -k noarch/repodata.json ......... Solving
>   package specifications: .
>
> Package plan for installation in environment
>   C:\Users\sofirx077029\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3:
>
> The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:
>
> ```
> xlrd: 1.0.0-py36_0 defaults
> ```
>
> Proceed ([y]/n)? n
>
> Exiting

In my .condarc I also tried:

```
channels:
  - file:///C:/Users/sofirx077029/Desktop/cache
  - defaults
```

It is clear by the warning that my channel is invalid, I should I do that? 
Please help, what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks very much

Comment: Does this question help? http://stackoverflow.com/q/35359147/2449192

Comment: I think you have added channel correctly But you also have to create repodata.json and repodata.json.bz2 file inside noarch directory then after index you private channel and then try conda install <packag name> I am sure it will work for 100%.