# conda - R Essentials missing dependencies on offline private repository

Tags: r, linux, redhat, conda

I'm currenty trying to install R essentials package for Anaconda on virtual Linux RedHat machine which doesn't have access to internet (that's why usual

> conda install c -r r-essentials

won't work). To do that I've downloaded from [air gap](http://airgap.demo.continuum.io) repository linux-64-pkgs.tar file from 2017-08/anaconda-server-sync-conda/ directory and used only r (r\pkgs\linux-64) directory from it.

Then I followed the instructions from this [link](https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=zh-CN&tl=en&js=y&prev=_t&hl=ru&ie=UTF-8&u=http%3A%2F%2Fpre.tir.tw%2F008%2Fblog%2Foutput%2Fr-package-install-offline.html&edit-text=&act=url). Since the directory contained repodata.json and repodata.json.bz2, it is not necessary to build and index files by following [this instruction](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35605508). After i run

> conda install r-essentials

happens this:

```
Fetching package metadata ....
WARNING: The remote server could not find the noarch directory for the
requested channel with url: file:///home/math/conda-r/repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r

It is possible you have given conda an invalid channel. Please double-check
your conda configuration using `conda config --show`.

If the requested url is in fact a valid conda channel, please request that the
channel administrator create `noarch/repodata.json` and associated
`noarch/repodata.json.bz2` files, even if `noarch/repodata.json` is empty.
$ mkdir noarch
$ echo '{}' > noarch/repodata.json
$ bzip2 -k noarch/repodata.json
.
Solving package specifications:

PackageNotFoundError: Dependencies missing in current linux-64 channels:
  - r-essentials -> r 3.2.1* -> r-base 3.2.1 -> ncurses
  - r-essentials -> r 3.2.1* -> r-recommended 3.2.1 -> r-boot
  - r-essentials -> r 3.2.1* -> r-recommended 3.2.1 -> r-class -> r-mass
  - r-essentials -> r 3.2.1* -> r-recommended 3.2.1 -> r-cluster
  - r-essentials -> r 3.2.1* -> r-recommended 3.2.1 -> r-codetools
  - r-essentials -> r 3.2.1* -> r-recommended 3.2.1 -> r-foreign
  - r-essentials -> r 3.2.1* -> r-recommended 3.2.1 -> r-kernsmooth
  - r-essentials -> r 3.2.1* -> r-recommended 3.2.1 -> r-lattice
  - r-essentials -> r 3.2.1* -> r-recommended 3.2.1 -> r-matrix
  - r-essentials -> r 3.2.1* -> r-recommended 3.2.1 -> r-mgcv -> r-nlme >=3.1_64
  - r-essentials -> r 3.2.1* -> r-recommended 3.2.1 -> r-nnet
  - r-essentials -> r 3.2.1* -> r-recommended 3.2.1 -> r-rpart
  - r-essentials -> r 3.2.1* -> r-recommended 3.2.1 -> r-spatial
  - r-essentials -> r 3.2.1* -> r-recommended 3.2.1 -> r-survival
  - r-essentials -> r-caret -> r-bradleyterry2 -> r-brglm -> r-profilemodel
  - r-essentials -> r-caret -> r-bradleyterry2 -> r-gtools
  - r-essentials -> r-caret -> r-bradleyterry2 -> r-lme4 >=1.0 -> r-minqa >=1.1.15 -> r-rcpp >=0.9.10
  - r-essentials -> r-caret -> r-bradleyterry2 -> r-lme4 >=1.0 -> r-nloptr >=1.0.4 -> nlopt
  - r-essentials -> r-caret -> r-bradleyterry2 -> r-lme4 >=1.0 -> r-rcppeigen
  - r-essentials -> r-caret -> r-car -> r-pbkrtest >=0.3_2
  - r-essentials -> r-caret -> r-car -> r-quantreg -> r-sparsem
  - r-essentials -> r-caret -> r-car -> r-quantreg -> r-matrixmodels
  - r-essentials -> r-caret -> r-foreach -> r-iterators
  - r-essentials -> r-caret -> r-ggplot2 -> r-digest
  - r-essentials -> r-caret -> r-ggplot2 -> r-gtable >=0.1.1
  - r-essentials -> r-caret -> r-ggplot2 -> r-plyr >=1.7.1
  - r-essentials -> r-caret -> r-ggplot2 -> r-proto
  - r-essentials -> r-caret -> r-ggplot2 -> r-reshape2 -> r-stringr -> r-magrittr
  - r-essentials -> r-caret -> r-ggplot2 -> r-reshape2 -> r-stringr -> r-stringi >=0.4.1
  - r-essentials -> r-caret -> r-ggplot2 -> r-scales >=0.2.3 -> r-dichromat
  - r-essentials -> r-caret -> r-ggplot2 -> r-scales >=0.2.3 -> r-labeling
  - r-essentials -> r-caret -> r-ggplot2 -> r-scales >=0.2.3 -> r-munsell >=0.2 -> r-colorspace
  - r-essentials -> r-caret -> r-ggplot2 -> r-scales >=0.2.3 -> r-rcolorbrewer
  - r-essentials -> r-caret -> r-ggplot2 -> r-lazyeval
  - r-essentials -> r-caret -> r-ggplot2 -> r-tibble -> r-assertthat
  - r-essentials -> r-caret -> r-ggplot2 -> r-tibble -> r-rlang
  - r-essentials -> r-caret -> r-modelmetrics >=1.1.0
  - r-essentials -> r-data.table -> r-chron
  - r-essentials -> r-dplyr -> r-bh >=1.58.0_1
  - r-essentials -> r-dplyr -> r-dbi >=0.3
  - r-essentials -> r-dplyr -> r-r6
  - r-essentials -> r-dplyr -> r-bindrcpp -> r-bindr
  - r-essentials -> r-dplyr -> r-bindrcpp -> r-plogr
  - r-essentials -> r-dplyr -> r-glue
  - r-essentials -> r-dplyr -> r-pkgconfig
  - r-essentials -> r-glmnet
  - r-essentials -> r-jsonlite
  - r-essentials -> r-quantmod -> r-ttr >=0.2 -> r-xts >=0.9_3 -> r-zoo >=1.7_10
  - r-essentials -> r-quantmod -> r-curl
  - r-essentials -> r-randomforest
  - r-essentials -> r-rmarkdown -> r-catools -> r-bitops
  - r-essentials -> r-rmarkdown -> r-htmltools >=0.2.4
  - r-essentials -> r-rmarkdown -> r-knitr >=1.6 -> r-evaluate >=0.6
  - r-essentials -> r-rmarkdown -> r-knitr >=1.6 -> r-formatr
  - r-essentials -> r-rmarkdown -> r-knitr >=1.6 -> r-highr
  - r-essentials -> r-rmarkdown -> r-knitr >=1.6 -> r-markdown -> r-mime >=0.3
  - r-essentials -> r-rmarkdown -> r-knitr >=1.6 -> r-yaml >=2.1.5
  - r-essentials -> r-rmarkdown -> r-base64enc
  - r-essentials -> r-rmarkdown -> r-rprojroot -> r-backports
  - r-essentials -> r-rmarkdown -> pandoc >=1.15.0
  - r-essentials -> r-shiny -> r-httpuv >=1.3.2
  - r-essentials -> r-shiny -> r-rjsonio
  - r-essentials -> r-shiny -> r-xtable
  - r-essentials -> r-shiny -> r-sourcetools
  - r-essentials -> r-tidyr
  - r-essentials -> r-irkernel -> ipython-notebook
  - r-essentials -> r-irkernel -> r-irdisplay -> r-repr
  - r-essentials -> r-irkernel -> r-rzmq >=0.7.0
  - r-essentials -> r-irkernel -> r-uuid
  - r-essentials -> r-irkernel -> r-pbdzmq >=0.2_1
  - r-essentials -> r-irkernel -> r-crayon -> r-memoise
  - r-essentials -> r-rbokeh -> r-hexbin
  - r-essentials -> r-rbokeh -> r-htmlwidgets
  - r-essentials -> r-rbokeh -> r-maps
  - r-essentials -> r-rbokeh -> r-gistr -> r-httr >=1.0.0 -> r-openssl >=0.8
  - r-essentials -> r-rbokeh -> r-pryr
  - r-essentials -> r-broom >=0.4.1 -> r-psych -> r-mnormt
  - r-essentials -> r-forcats >=0.1.1
  - r-essentials -> r-haven >=1.0.0 -> r-hms
  - r-essentials -> r-haven >=1.0.0 -> r-readr >=0.1.0
  - r-essentials -> r-lubridate >=1.6.0
  - r-essentials -> r-modelr >=0.1.0 -> r-purrr >=0.2.2
  - r-essentials -> r-readxl >=0.1.1 -> r-cellranger -> r-rematch
  - r-essentials -> r-rvest >=0.3.2 -> r-selectr
  - r-essentials -> r-rvest >=0.3.2 -> r-xml2
  - r-essentials -> r-tidyverse >=1.0.0

Close matches found; did you mean one of these?

    nlopt: r-nloptr
    pandoc: pango

(and similarly for the other packages)
```

I also copied these repodata.* files to /noarch directory, but nothing changed except part between `Fetching package metadata ....` and `Solving package specifications:` is now not shown.

Is it conda r package issue or I'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem.But the difference is that I followed [the post](http://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000014951) and only downloaded the required packages. But unexpectedly, I found the package `r-base` was not downloaded. So I downloaded it again.
Then I built the conda repo by the command `conda index`. When I used the following command:

```
conda install r r-essentials -c file:///opt/kevin/channel --override-channels
```

It didn't make work.I would update r-base with the default channel(it needs internet)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3UyXv.png)