# How To Create a Local Web-based Anaconda Channel?

Tags: python, anaconda

**How does one create a local conda channel that is web based instead of file based?**

There is [an existing question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35359147/how-can-i-host-my-own-private-conda-repository) on custom channels but the solution is file based, e.g.

```
conda -c file://...
```

Similarly, [the documentation](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/create-custom-channels.html) covers file channels pretty well.

However, I am looking for an artifact repository or other http solution.

Thank you in advance for your consideration and response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The minimalist approach is a web server serving a conda-compatible directory structure. Here's one example how to build it using Nginx and Docker.

https://www.cityscience.com/blog/private-conda-channel.html

But if you need a robust control over access privileges and the ability to search for and browse packages you may want to consider licensing [Anaconda Enterprise](https://www.anaconda.com/enterprise/).

Comment: Great solution. I'm not sure why this isn't more common. PyPi servers are fairly popular. How do you upload conda packages to it? can you use `anaconda upload`?