# How do I upload my conda package to a local http anaconda channel?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

Is it possible to upload a conda package to a local http conda channel? There seems to be no flag for this using `anaconda upload`.

For those unfamiliar using local conda channels, here is some background. The [conda documentation](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/create-custom-channels.html) says:

> If you do not wish to upload your packages to the Internet, you can build a custom repository served either through a web server or locally.

As far as I can tell, there is only 1 [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50862925/how-to-create-a-local-web-based-anaconda-channel) on the whole of SO detailing how to do this. And no questions/answers detailing how to actually upload your files to it. I know it's possible to upload to a private channel `anaconda.org` but I'm currently working for an air-gapped team with no access to outside internet.

Comment: I don't know the answer, but I suggest you take a look at `anaconda config --help` and see how to set a site/API location, then I suspect `anaconda upload` will work

Comment: Hmm, It would take me a while to set up a channel on a server just to test that this works. But this was my assumption too so I may just have to give it a go. Another option is to use [conan.io](https://conan.io/) which seems much more well documented.