# install a python package from private pypi using conda

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, conda

I'm new to Conda and recently changed to a MacBook with the M1 chip, so there are some packages that are easier or only available to install with Conda, that's why I'm using Conda.

What I'm trying to do is this but with Conda:

```
pip install --index-url https://<private-pypi> private-package
```

Couldn't find a way to achieve this, any clue what can I do?

Answer (score 0):

If its versioned in git that you can use this template to help get package:

```
pip install git+https://{token}@gitprovider.com/user/project.git@{version}
```

If you need to install pip within your conda env:

```
conda install pip
```

This gist should help: https://gist.github.com/Jaza/fcea493dd0ba6ebf09d3

In PyPi, there is the private-pypi package:
https://pypi.org/project/private-pypi/
But I don't know how much its going to help you. I don't think you need this, your usage sounds much simpler.

In Github, you need to make sure your repository has developer tokens set up for you to use:
https://techglimpse.com/git-push-github-token-based-passwordless/

Comment: I need to use `Conda` instead of `pip` and also this is talking about a private git repository and I have a pypi index

Comment: I have updated my answer. Installing pip using conda should make pip available and function within your conda virtual env.

Comment: But I need to use `Conda` instead of `pip`. Because some packages cannot be installed with `pip` with the Mac with M1 chip. What I need to do would be something like `conda install --index-url <private-pypi-url> <private-package>` but the flag `--index-url´ doesn't exist

Comment: Sorry didn't realize M1 chip prevents pip usage. Check this SO post I believe this is the only way to do what you want: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35605508/2175781